# Persistence of homoclinic points - the noncompact case

Tags: dynamical-systems

It is well known that transverse homoclinic points of $C^1$-diffeomorphisms of compact manifolds $M$ persist under small $C^1$ perturbations.

Does the same hold for non-compact manifolds (with the usual Whitney topology on the set of all $C^1$ diffeomorphisms)?